# How to send/recieve parameters in GET Request body using CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I know that this is not a REST standard. But, is there such a way that we can include parameters such as JSON in the body of a GET request? I'm using Apache CXF for both service and client.

Comment: It's not an HTTP standard either.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON was minified and encoded correctly, it could be passed as a parameter in a URL.